# Explain Why StackOverFlow error raised in this Program..?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, stack-overflow

I was practicing java, and i wrote this program and once i run it, this raise an error StackOverFlow Error why ?

```
public class MyClass { 

   MyClass  s=new MyClass();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         MyClass  s1=new MyClass();

        System.out.println("Sum of x+y = ");
    }
}
```

Exception StackTrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:3)
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:5)
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:5)
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:5)
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:5)
    at com.practice.java.dev.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:5)
```

Why so, Please explain it in deep ??

Comment: Your class `MyClass` has a field `s` that is initialised to contain another instance of `MyClass`. And that instance has to contain another instance, and so on until stack overflow. You're not using that field; you could just delete it.

Comment: I think you will find a previous [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679832/java-stackoverflowerror-when-local-and-instance-objects-creation) on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your main creates a `MyClass` instance:

```
MyClass  s1=new MyClass();
```

Before the `MyClass` constructor's body is executed, all the instance variables are initialized, which executes:

```
MyClass s = new MyClass();
```

This creates a second instance of `MyClass`, and before that constructor's body is executed, the instance variable `s` of that second instance is initialized, leading to the creation of a 3rd `MyClass` instance. And so on...

In other words, you are creating an infinite number of `MyClass` instances recursively. This leads to an infinite recursion and `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a class of MyClass inside MyClass, which results in an "infinite" depth of these classes getting created all the time, until you get StackOverflow.