# creating an object outside main and user defined method scope gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Tags: java

[Here is the link for code snippet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sQAt.png)

Comment: Flagged for closing as it stays unclear what's the issue and what's the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java StackOverflowError when local and instance objects creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679832/java-stackoverflowerror-when-local-and-instance-objects-creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line

```
Sample obj3 = new Sample();
```

because that will result in an endless loop (creating an instance of `Sample` while during the creation of an instance of `Sample`), causing your `StackOverflowError`.

And please dont post code as an image.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I tried to write the code but due to some indentation error, stack overflow was not accepting. I am new to Java. so when I create an object "obj 1" the heap memory and stack memory will be initialized for the instance variable and local variable and class variable will be initialized in method area. So where and how will the above statement for "obj3" creation will be stored or initialized

Comment: `obj3` is declared as a field (because it't not inside of any method) of `Sample` and will be initialized with an instance of `Sample` when ever the surrounding instance is created. You create an `obj1` in your `main`, which creates an `obj3`, which creates an `obj3`, ... and this goes on until you run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks but if its recursive, is it possible to have objects with same name

Comment: Of course it is, but each new instance of `Sample` creates a new, inner instance of `Sample`. This recursion goes on forever and never stops.