# OO: Does container contain bike or chair?

Tags: java, oop

A container may contain bikes and chairs, both belonging to a person. I would like to check, if the container contains either bikes or chairs of said person. Is this possible without using `instanceof`?

```
public class Container {

    public Map<Person, List<Item>> items = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(Person p, Item item) {
        items.get(p).add(item);
    }

    public boolean containsChair(Person owner) {
        for(Item i : items.get(owner)) {
            if(i instanceof Chair) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean containsBike(Person owner) {
        for(Item i : items.get(owner)) {
            if(i instanceof Bike) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

For the purpose of illustration, Item, Bike, Chair, Person are all simplest class stubs:

```
public class Person { public String name; }
public abstract class Item {}
public class Bike extends Item { public Wheel[] wheels;}
public class Chair extends Item { public Leg[] legs;}
public class Wheel {}
public class Leg {}
```

In the runner, a Person should be able to add Chairs and Bikes to its container:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container c = new Container();
        Person p = new Person();

        // Prevent null pointer exception
        c.items.put(p, new ArrayList<>());

        c.add(p, new Chair());

        // True
        System.out.println(c.containsChair(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the visitor pattern and mix it with three lists, one pair type you are searching. Check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458676/how-to-avoid-instanceof-when-implementing-factory-design-pattern

Comment: There are multiple options. This thread also will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'instanceof' when implementing factory design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458676/how-to-avoid-instanceof-when-implementing-factory-design-pattern)

Comment: I suggest you to use visitor pattern,

Visitor pattern's purpose with examples

It is a good practise to avoide instance of

Comment: Stay away from the visitor pattern as much as possible. [It may stab you in the back...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48811/what-design-patterns-are-the-worst-or-most-narrowly-defined)

Answer (score 5):

You could add to class `Item` an abstract method `ItemType getType()`. `ItemType` would be an enum enumerating all possible item types.

```
public abstract class Item {
    public abstract ItemType getType();
}

public enum ItemType {
    BIKE, CHAIR;
}
```

Implementation of `Chair`:

```
public static class Chair extends Item {
    public Leg[] legs;
    @Override
    public ItemType getType() {
        return ItemType.CHAIR;
    }
}
```

Then you could define a `contains` method to search for a the given `Person` if it has an item with a certain `ItemType`:

```
public boolean contains(Person owner, ItemType itemType) {
    return items.get(owner).stream().anyMatch(item ->itemType.equals(item.getType()));
}
```

Or null-safe regarding the `owner`s `items` list:

```
public boolean contains(Person owner, ItemType itemType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(items.get(owner))
            .map(i -> i.stream().anyMatch(item -> itemType.equals(item.getType())))
            .orElse(false);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Container c = new Container();
    Person p = new Person();

    // Prevent null pointer exception
    c.items.put(p, new ArrayList<>());

    c.add(p, new Chair());

    // True
    System.out.println(c.contains(p, ItemType.CHAIR));        
}
```

EDIT
Following this approach there is no need for `instanceof` checks. The usage of `instanceof` can be a hint indicating [that the design has some flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526896/2838289).

Comment: Good to know that it has brought you forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `Bike` and `Chair` in two different datastructure.

```
public final class Container {
    private final Map<Person, List<Chair>> chairs = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Person, List<Bike>> bikes = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(Person p, Chair chair) {
        chairs.putIfAbsent(p, new ArrayList<Chair>());
        chairs.get(p).add(chair);
    }

    public void add(Person p, Bike bike) {
        bikes.putIfAbsent(p, new ArrayList<Bike>());
        bikes.get(p).add(bike);
    }

    public boolean containsChair(Person owner) {
        return chairs.getOrDefault(owner, Collections.emptyList()).size() > 0;
    }

    public boolean containsBike(Person owner) {
        return bikes.getOrDefault(owner, Collections.emptyList()).size() > 0;
    }
}
```

Note that I also made your instance fields `private` to hide the fact that data is stored in a `Map` and avoid the runner code to have the responsibility to instanciate an `ArrayList` if not existant. Both the class and its fields are also `final` to achieve a better immutability. Both encapsulation and immutability are considered good practices when doing OOP.

Usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Container c = new Container();
    Person p = new Person();
    c.add(p, new Chair());
    System.out.println(c.containsChair(p)); //true
    System.out.println(c.containsBike(p)); //false
}
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. But am trying to stay with one.

Comment: @TMOTTM Do you really need one ? i.e. is there another method that need to use both `Chair` and `Bike` together ? If not, it's not a smell to go this way.

Comment: I'm not sure, because then I could start building separate containers for bikes and chairs, and a container for the two containers.

Comment: @TMOTTM Either stay with one container or do 2 separate generic containers (without a "super-container").

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was to add two methods to `Item`:

```
public boolean containsBike() {return false;}
public boolean containsChair() {return false;}
```

While this certainly could be optimized, the check is now done by calling the method of the object:

```
public boolean containsBike(Person p) {
        boolean hasBike = false;
        // Prevent NullPointerException
        if(containsSomethingOf(p)) {
            for(Item i : items.get(p)) {
                if(i != null) {
                    if (i.containsBike()) {
                        hasBike = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return hasTrousers;
}
```

I think this is what is called polymorphism.

Comment: And where are these methods defined? What is the type of `g`? If these methods are defined on `Item` it*s not how it should be.

Comment: I corrected my post, it should have been `containsBike` instead of `isBike`. @LuCio They are in `Item` and then overriden in `Bike` and `Chair`. I find it at least a bit cleaner than using `instanceof` because now the objects know more about themselves. But of course open to further suggestions. Still need to try out the case from @Spotted

Comment: These methods are introducing [circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646113/circular-dependency-in-java-classes#3646139). More over the abstract [superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) `Item` has knowledge about it's subclasses. These classes aren't [loose coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). Thus this is not a sustainable design. Using `instanceof` is  "_a hint that your design has some flaws._" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526896/2838289)). I would reconsider the design.

Comment: LuCio is right, now `Item` depends on its subclasses, which it's not supposed to know anything about ! You should either use @LuCio's approach or mine.